# How to get text on same page after form submit using href?

Tags: javascript, php

I am submitting a form using an href link via POST method. When I submit the form I am not able to get the value of the PHP variable.

Here is my code

```
      if(($_POST)) {
    $users1 = $_POST['cityname'];
    echo $users1;
    echo "shakti";
 }

<td align="center"> 
<form action="searchresult.php" method="POST">

 <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;" onclick="parentNode.submit();" name="an">
    </form>
      <?php echo $row['city']; ?>
    <input type="text"  value="<?php echo $row['city'];?>" name="cityname">
    </a>
      </td>
```

How can I achieve my desired output?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Form element *inside* an anchor tag is **invalid HTML**.

```
  if(($_POST)) {
    $users1 = $_POST['cityname'];
    echo $users1;
    echo "shakti";
 }

    <td align="center"> 
    <form action="searchresult.php" name="form1" method="POST">
      <?php echo $row['city']; ?>
    <input type="text"  value="<?php echo $row['city'];?>" name="cityname">
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;" onclick="javascript:document.form1.submit();" name="an">SUBMIT</a>
</form>
      </td>
```